# Making an angle of 10 degree and its multiple using compass?

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

We all know very well how to make an angle of 15 and 45 degree and its multiple using compass. Can anybody tell me how to make an angle of 10 degree and its multiple using compass?

Answer (score 14):

It's not possible to construct an angle of $10$ degrees with straightedge and compass alone. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection for details.

Comment: More precisely: the minimal polynomial for $\sin\,10^\circ$ is an irreducible cubic, and that precludes constructibility with compass/straightedge. There's always neusis, however...

Answer (score -2):

yes we can, for that we first need to draw equilateral triangle & then divide opposite side of the triangle into 6 parts & then join them. In this way at the vertex of one of the opposite side you can find 10 degrees.

Comment: Dividing the opposite side into six equal parts? That won't work.

Comment: Dividing the _side_ equally does not in general divide the _angle_ equally!